# How to force a silent login attempt before validationg the access token in angular-oauth2-oidc

Tags: angular, single-sign-on, angular-oauth2-oidc

I'm using angular-oauth2-oidc for authentication. It's configured to use a 3rd partry SSO identity provider. The setup of my app follows https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards. The IdP doesn't implement [Session Status Change Notifications](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#ChangeNotification), but I need to know if the user logs out or changes while navigating back and forth between my site and the IdP. So I'd like repeat the authentication request with prompt=none every time the page loads, even if there is a non-expired access token in sessionStorage. I tried changing `runInitialLoginSequence` and executing `oauthService.silentRefresh()` before checking `oauthService.hasValidAccessToken()` but that leads to an endless loop.

So my question is what is the correct way to trigger an authentication request with prompt=none every time my page loads in this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Scenario 1: "page load" means "SPA load"

I reckon that if you change the `runInitialLoginSequence` to merely remove [the `hasValidAccesstoken` check](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards/blob/e49258887ce79baea500f3e6df7dd75463400368/src/app/core/auth.service.ts#L105-L107) then that should do the trick. Then the `silentRefresh` runs each time the APP_INITIALIZER runs (so every time your SPA is freshly loaded).

The `canActivateProtectedRoutes$` observable will not emit any value until both `isDoneLoading$` (the login sequence being done) emits, *and* the `isAuthenticated$` emits (which by default it always does, as it's a `BehaviorSubject` with a default of `false).

The guards will wait until `isDoneLoading$` emits, which won't happen until the `silentRefresh` has completed.

**Scenario 2: "page load" *also* means "Angular Route Change"**

So if you *also* want the silent refresh to do a check each time the route changes, you'll have to do extra modifications.

In this case you'll need to modify the guards and/or use Angular's [Router events](https://angular.io/guide/router-reference#router-events) to trigger the silent refresh, and make sure everyone waits until it has completed.

A straightforward (though perhaps not optimal or pretty) way to do it would be to change [the `AuthGuard` (the one without forced login)](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards/blob/master/src/app/core/auth-guard.service.ts) to something like this:

```
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot,
  ): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.waitForNewSilentRefreshCallToBeCompleted$ // << Changed
      .pipe(map(_ => this.authService.canActivateProtectedRoutes$) // << Changed
      .pipe(tap(x => console.log('You tried to go to ' + state.url + ' and this guard said ' + x)));
  }
```

Note that the `// << Changed` lines are pseudo-code, you'll have to implement something like that on the service yourself. It's not already in the sample.